# Why does zsh not autocomplete custom created scripts when bash does?

Tags: linux, bash, autocomplete, zsh

I have a custom created script to change my apt sources in `/home/USERNAME/Scripts`. I have added this path to the secure_path variable in `/etc/sudoers`.

When I use `bash` to run my script as `sudo` it autocompletes just fine, but when using `zsh` it does not.

Comment: Could you be more precise in explaining the problem? For instance, if I type `sudo ....` and the first few characters of the name of the program I want to _sudo_, it completes the program name if it is found in my PATH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `zsh` doesn't have autocompletion without adding it to `.zshrc`.
Look for a good `.zshrc` with autocompletion, on [GitHub for example](https://github.com/search?q=.zshrc) (As a fan of Fish and Zsh, i would recommend [this one](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions))...

If `.zshrc` is empty/absent, it's because you probably installed zsh after creating your own user, and then ran `chsh /path/to/zsh` which will not give you `.zshrc` (in ~/).